# javascript function display in a div

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

i created a javascript and did all the coding required and finally got a variable "bookerVar" i want this variable to be displayed at the bottom of my html page . How should i do it.

(longer explanation: i created a page where a person can choose from a drop down as he chooses from the drop down using javascript i do certain calculatons and finally store the last value in a variable called bookerVar which is in a function called bookersay().

the last line of the function says return bookerVar.

now what i want is that the value stored in bookerVar can be displayed at the bootom of my html page in a div tag).
can anyone tell me what do i have to write in my html code and my javascript (which is actually in a different file). Thanks.

Comment: could we see the script?

Comment: its actually not complete and would make little sense now but i would upload it later so that in future if someone comes to this page , it could be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this example that i created fits you. You can copy/paste in in some .html file and run it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Appending content to some div</title>
</head>     
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function appendToContent(html) {
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    content.appendChild(div);
}

appendToContent('hello world');
</script>
```

Comment: a small question my javascript is on another page and also can you please explain it using the variable bookerVer , ididnt understand the script after var div = document.createElement('div');

Comment: This was just a 'generic' example. The document.createElement('div') creates a new element, that is a div, and next, it appends some html to it. If you want to append the value of your bookerVer variable, just call appendToContent(bookerVer). Of course, you might need to do some changes to adapt this code to your page.

Comment: i am actually learning javascript by tutorials so i just know very little stuff. so all i have to do is replace the last line of code to appendToContent(bookerVar)??
Thank you so much for your help .

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how your code is structured, you might need to do some slight changes to my code.

Answer (score 3):

Place this in the `.html` doc that the bookerVar is currently located.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addDiv() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = bookerVar;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    }
    addDiv();
</script>
```

Comment: do i also have to do anything in the div tag in the html file in which i want it to show up. ??

Comment: No, I depending on what `bookerVar` is, I would suggest surrounding it in a `<p>` tag or `<span>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to tell you is to get [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), then use something like this:

```
$("body").append("<div>" + bookerVar + "</div>");
```

Comment: There is no mention of jquery..?

Comment: actually pure DOM would be easier imo.

Comment: i just know enough javascript to do what i mentioned before. I am learning javascript by using tutorials and have no idea of jquery. But still thanks.